# Aligning h1 and input fields in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i have a row in bootstrap containing a h1 class and input field. This is my code

```
<div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col h1 text-white text-start text-center text-md-start text-lg-start">Welcome<input class="form-control no-border font-size" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"></div>
        </div>
```

The desired output i am looking for is "Welcome name" where "Welcome" and "Name" is aligned side by side. However my current output is as shown below

[image: current output]

Is there any form of styling that i can do using bootstrap to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using **Bootstrap** only, the trick is done using the `col-auto` CSS class like the following

```
<div class="row mb-5">
  <div class="col-auto h1 text-white text-start text-center text-md-start text-lg-start">
    Welcome
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input class="form-control no-border font-size" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

You see in here, the first child of the row represents a `col-auto` that spans only the required space *The Welcome word*, and the second child takes the rest space remaining in the `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Append d-inline on the class of the second div.
On welcome div and it should work.

```
<div class="row mb-5">
  <div class="col h1 text-white text-start text-center text-md-start text-lg-start d-inline">Welcome
      <input class="form-control no-border font-size" type="text" placeholder="EnterName">
  </div>
</div>
```

Also there are some examples of horizontals forms on
[bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid)